# How can I capture the "Stop" button being pressed in the iOS debugger?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm debugging an iOS app, and I need to call some cleanup code in some C++ classes (really, i just want their destructors to be called). When I run the app via XCode with the device attached, and then stop it by pressing the stop button, *none* of the app delegate methods are called (I'm looking specifically at `applicationWillTerminate`). However, if I pick up the device and press the home button, it successfully calls both `applicationDidEnterBackground` and `applicationWillResignActive`.

What am I doing wrong? I've tried removing all references to any C++ code, effectively making a blank iOS app, and I simply cannot get `applicationWillTerminate` to be called, or even `dealloc` in the root view controller. I've even tried using the `signal()` method along with SIGABRT, SIGKILL, etc., and that does nothing (plus, I can't call the Objective-C methods from a C method anyway). How can I react to the stop button being pressed?

Answer (score 2):

You aren't doing anything wrong, the system just kills your app when you press on the `stop` button.

There are no methods called because the app is just killed, the same thing can happen when you app is backgrouded and the system needs more memory.

Comment: Blah. I have open TCP connections in the C++ classes that need to be cleaned up. That's annoying! Thanks for the response. Quick follow-up: all apps exit with a seg fault. I've tried creating a blank app, and if I hit the stop button, the console always shows a seg fault. Is that normal?

Comment: Yep, that's normal. You could, just before you hit the stop button, send the app to the background. Then the `applicationDidEnterBackground` will be called.

Answer (score 1):

For more precision for the methods called when the app exits / enter in background, [check this page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3)

Like @rckoenes said, when you stop the app with the debugger, it kills it.

If your app has the background capability (UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend = NO, it's the default mode), when you quit your app, it is placed in the background instead terminated.

Comment: Very helpful! I'll try doing this and just avoid stopping the app using the stop button.